# will it work with no drivers?

Tags: system-installation

So my question is will Ubuntu Install when your computer has no drivers what so ever? my friend didn't know what he was doing and completely formatted his hard drives so lost every thing so were trying to get some type of os on it so we can make sure the whole computer isn't completely trashed...

Comment: If you wiped the drive installing another os will make sure the files stay deleted... I would recommend using the "try ubuntu" option of the install disk to check it out first before installing

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it will work perfectly. Linux is not windows. Many drivers are included, when you tick the checkbox " install drivers while installing Ubuntu"